# Listview in ListFragment error in add method

Tags: android, listview

Hello guys I  am facing problem in mItems.add() it takes parameter int and Collection type. I gave parameter as int and also passing some string values. I dont understand why there is an error on add.

private List mItems;        // ListView items list

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // initialize the items list
        mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
        Resources resources = getResources();
        DBHandler dbh = new DBHandler(getContext());
        String friend_name, friend_status,friend_date_time,friend_fb_id;
        String fb_url;
        Cursor cursor = dbh.readAllFriends(dbh);
        int a=0;
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            friend_name                 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TableInfo.F_USER_NAME));
            friend_status           =   cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TableInfo.F_USER_STATUS));
            friend_date_time    =   cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TableInfo.F_DATE));
            friend_fb_id                =   cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TableInfo.F_FACEBOOK_ID));
            fb_url="https://graph.facebook.com/"+friend_fb_id+"/picture?type=large";
            mItems.add(a, fb_url,friend_name,friend_status,friend_date_time);
        }
        cursor.close();
```

Comment: Add the following line in your while loop

Answer (score 1):

You did wrong. Do like

```
ListViewItem item =new ListViewItem(a, fb_url,friend_name,friend_status,friend_date_time);

mItems.add(item );
```

you should add `ListViewItem`  Object on `mItems ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

In add() argument should be of ListViewItem type,
so  pass the reference of ListViewItem in add().

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in your while loop at last

Change

```
mItems.add(a, fb_url,friend_name,friend_status,friend_date_time);
```

To

```
ListViewItem obj=new ListViewItem(a, fb_url,friend_name,friend_status,friend_date_time);
mList.add(obj);
```

In your ListViewItem class add a constructor

```
ListViewItem(a, fb_url,friend_name,friend_status,friend_date_time);
{

}
```

Hope this helps.